# Finding lines that contain all the strings

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to search a txt file and only find lines that containing all the strings. There is min=1 and max=4 string.

I made a little research and i got this code from [ss64](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) its working but just for 2 strings.

```
findstr /irc:"!str[1]!.*!str[2]!" /c:"!str[2]!.*!str[1]!" %MINDEX%
```

How can i expend this code ? Is there a better way ?

Search strings (`!str[1]!` to `!str[4]!`):

```
aaa
bbb
123
321
```

Txt file which is searched (`%MINDEX%`):

```
aaa aaa bbb ccc 123
123 bbb ccc 321 aaa
321 ccc aaa eee ddd
```

Desired output:

```
123 bbb ccc 321 aaa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is totally impractical, since you need every permutaton, which is the factorial of the number of strings:

```
1! =   1
2! =   2
3! =   6
4! =  24
5! = 120
6! = 720
```

The solution is to search for one string at a time, piping the result of one search into the next, until all strings are exhausted. It looks like your search terms are string literals, so no regex needed.

```
findstr /ic:"!str[1]!" "%mindex%" | findstr /ic:"!str[2]!" | findstr /ic:"!str[3]!" | findstr /ic:"!str[4]!"
```

[edited:Magoo - see comment]

Command line length is limited to 8192 bytes, so there is a limit to the number of FINDSTR commands that you can string together. Plus, this also becomes impractical as the number of strings increases.

The final step to generalize the solution is to iterate the search strings.

```
copy "%mindex%" result.txt
for /l %%N in (1 1 %maxN%) do (
  findstr /ic:"!str[%%N]!" result.txt >result.txt.tmp
  move /y result.txt.tmp result.txt
)
type result.txt
del result.txt
```

Comment: OP's requirement appears to be to select lines containing all of the strings in any order. Suspect typo in dbenham solution (cascaded `findstr`) showed [1][2][2][3] - modified to [1][2][3][4].

Comment: I just added `if DEFINED str[%%N]` inside the for loop before the other commands and now its work for any number of variable. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically generate the filter (in this case reading the strings from a file)

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "filter= "
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("strings.txt") do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!filter!") do (
            endlocal
            set "filter=%%b | find /i "%%~a" "
        )
    )

    type "data.txt" %filter% > "output.txt"
```

But as command lines are limited to 8192 characters, the size of strings can be a problem with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution: this should be very quick on large files also

```
@echo off
set str[1]=aaa
set str[2]=bbb
set str[3]=123
set str[4]=321

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
type "file.txt" | findrepl "^(?=.*!str[1]!)(?=.*!str[2]!)(?=.*!str[3]!)(?=.*!str[4]!).*$" /i
pause
```

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` (by aacini) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

Create test file:

```
@echo off
(
echo aaa aaa bbb ccc 123
echo 123 bbb ccc 321 aaa
echo 321 ccc aaa eee ddd
)>file.txt
```